# How to assign different name to data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the code:

```
i<-1
while(i<5)
{
  df+i <-data.frame()
  df+i<-c(i,i+1)
  i<-i+1

}
```

Instead  of `i` numbers are expected.  I want to create objects `df1` ,`df2`, `df3`, etc.

I tried   `assign(paste("a", i, sep = ""), i)`

but its not working.

Comment: i want data frame with different name in "LOOP"

Comment: @Joshua Ulrich
  above link is not my expected answer..
that gives only create data frame but not adding value in it

data+i<-c(i,i+)
is not possbile in above answer

Comment: No, it's not _exactly_ your expected answer, but getting your expected answer is trivial using the linked question. Sorry, but I expected you to do _some_ work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (i in 1:5){assign(paste("df",i,sep=""),data.frame())}
```

Comment: is it possible to assign value in same loop ??

Comment: Yes. What values? Please provide an example.

Comment: df+i <-data.frame()
  df+i<-c(i,i+1)
  i<-i+1

Comment: Does this mean you want each data frame to have 2 columns and 1 row, or 1 column and 2 rows? The way it's written you will get the latter. Just replace `data.frame()` with `data.frame(c(i,i+1))`.

Comment: is it possible to print in same loop
i mean print(a+i)..any option??